# How do I get rid of the Unity Dash in Gnome classic?

Tags: compiz, unity-dash, gnome-classic

I tried to enable Compiz features like wobbly windows and Desktop cube, but doing so Compiz crashed.

After it restarted Dash was started as well. I logged of and back onto my Gnome classic environment, but the Dash still starts.

How can I get rid of the Dash again so I can use Gnome classic as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On CCSM you should have an option to enable and disable Unity as a plugin. My guess is that the option is enabled at the moment.

[image]

Check that and disable the Unity plugin in CCSM if enabled.

Comment: yes, u are right. that option is enabled now ... thnks for the fast response.